# Upload file using Apache FTP Client does not work

Tags: java, android, apache, ftp

I have read a half dozen threads regarding this and I'm no where closer to a solution. No matter what I change I get ftp return code 500 "The command was not accepted and the requested action did not take place." and I'm not sure how to debug that.

This is my site and I can connect with CoreFTP and read and write, so it does not seem to be a permissions issue. I've tried two different accounts, with this code and CoreFTP. One writes to the root and another is pointed to an "image_in" folder.

imageData is a byte array with a length of 166578 and stream has the same length after the InputStream call. storeFile() always returns false with a return code of 500.

One thread implied enterLocalPassiveMode() and enterRemotePassiveMode() were the culprits, but I have tried this code both with and without those lines and still I get a 500 return code.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Greg

```
class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... unsued) {
        try {
            boolean status = false;
            try {
                FTPClient mFtpClient = new FTPClient();
                String ip = "my domain dot com";
                String userName = "ftp79815757-0";
                String pass = "my password";

                mFtpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(ip));
                mFtpClient.login(userName, pass);
                int reply = mFtpClient.getReplyCode();
                if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {

        //one thread said this would do the trick
                    mFtpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                    mFtpClient.enterRemotePassiveMode();

                    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);

                    mFtpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/images_in");                        
                    String currdir = mFtpClient.printWorkingDirectory();

                    if (!mFtpClient.storeFile("remoteName.jpg", stream)) {
                        Log.e("FTPUpload", String.valueOf(mFtpClient.getReplyCode()));
                    }

                    stream.close(); 
                    mFtpClient.disconnect();
                }
                else {
                    Log.e("FTPConnected", String.valueOf(reply));
                }
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any other exceptions? And have you added the required permissions in your Manifest.xml ?

Comment: No Java exceptions in the code and no other FTP exceptions. The permissions in the manifest are Internet, write external storage, and read contacts. Internet was added when I incorporated FTP. Are other manifest permissions needed?

Comment: I have also tried to explicitly set the port to 21 and I use both mFtpClient.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE) and mFtpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); Still get return code 500,

Comment: So you want to upload files from android using FTP .. which example are you following on the internet ? If you're using `ftp4j` then there are many working examples

Comment: Yes, ftp from android. All of the examples I've seen use org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set **file type**

```
mFtpClient.setFileType(org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

If it still doesn't work then you have following options:

If you insist on using `Apache FTP Client` then follow [this example](http://royvandewater.com/2010/10/uploading-a-file-to-ftp-with-android/)

Or you could try [this example](http://androidexample.com/FTP_File_Upload_From_Sdcard_to_server/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=98&aaid=120)

The second example worked in my case.

Comment: Thanks, but if you look at my comments above, I tried that and still get code 500. I don't insist on using anything. When I search for Java FTP Apache came up repeatedly. I changed to ftp4j, but now have different problems, which will require a new question. The examples you list are the same thing I've over and over. The real difference is they are sending a file from file system, where mine is InputStream, which is an important change. I wonder if that is the key.

Comment: The first example using `ftp4j` uses `BufferedInputStream` but that example is almost 5 years old. Things change. So yeah try to upload a simple file from file directory first.See If that works. If it works then you may get somewhere

Comment: It's FTP, how much could it change? Anyway, I assume you're implying 5 years old is bad, but maybe not. Is BufferedInputStream better than InputStream? I'll try a file.

Comment: Yes `BufferedInputStream` is better. And by saying its old, its not meant for FTP itself, but the Underlying OS support for such libraries. I maybe wrong though.

Comment: Switched to a file path instead of byte array and still got return code 500. {Whimper} I wrote my first FTP client in Visual Basic 3 about 20 years ago. Who knew this is what would bring me to my knees in Java. This question documents the strange problems I'm having with ftp4j http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146653/asynctask-does-not-execute. I used to have a love/hate relationship with Java. Now I just hate it.

Comment: Well on the contrary I love Java. I have a career because of it. And oh I forgot to mention, the FTP examples, in the second one, it states that the server must have a 'dedicated IP'

Comment: *sigh* Well I guess now the place to check is your server. Since its not a permission issue or anything. Its not from android side. Error Response code 500 means that server encountered some unexpected condition. You should log something on your server to see what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use: [enterLocalPassiveMode](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#enterLocalPassiveMode())

```
mFtpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```

If you then do other operations, you might have to go back active with [enterLocalActiveMode](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#enterLocalActiveMode()).