# AsyncTask does not execute

Tags: java, android

I'm in Android Studio.

There are two async tasks below. The top one was the original and when I call new ImageUploadTask().execute(); it fires as expected and I can add break points and step through the code. I was having problems with the ftp code and someone suggested I switched from Apache to ftpj4.

I cut out the try catch block with the Apache code and added in the ftp4j code. Now when I call new ImageUploadTask().execute(); it never goes in to the async task.

I can go back and forth: add in the Apache block and it works and in the ftp4j code and it never enters the async task. If I put a break point on ImageUploadTask().execute(); and press F8 it goes in to view.java instead of ImageUploadTask.

At the very bottom is the on click listener which never changes. I change imports, sync the gradle, clean, and rebuild between changes.

Apache code

```
class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String>{
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... unused) {
    try {
        boolean status = false;
        try {
            FTPClient mFtpClient = new FTPClient();
            String ip = "my domain dot com";
            String userName = "ftp79815757-0";
            String pass = "my password";

            mFtpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(ip));
            mFtpClient.login(userName, pass);
            int reply = mFtpClient.getReplyCode();
            if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {

    //one thread said this would do the trick
                mFtpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                mFtpClient.enterRemotePassiveMode();

                InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);

                mFtpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/images_in");                        
                String currdir = mFtpClient.printWorkingDirectory();

                if (!mFtpClient.storeFile("remoteName.jpg", stream)) {
                    Log.e("FTPUpload", String.valueOf(mFtpClient.getReplyCode()));
                }

                stream.close(); 
                mFtpClient.disconnect();
            }
            else {
                Log.e("FTPConnected", String.valueOf(reply));
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Error",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

ftp4j

```
class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... unused) {

        try {
            FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
            ftpClient.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);
            ftpClient.connect("my domain dot com");
            ftpClient.login("ftp79815757-0", "my password");
            InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);
            ftpClient.upload("testsfile.jpg", stream,0,0,new MyFTPListener());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

         }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unused) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {
        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

click listener

```
upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new ImageUploadTask().execute();
        }
});
```

Comment: Anything interesting in the logs you run the `ftp4j` version?

Comment: The log outputs are identical from what I can tell. Maybe 30 lines. All black text except some light blue text regarding w/ResolverActivity and then W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ reportFullscreenMode on inactive InputConnection. No exceptions.

Comment: Well, now both stopped executing. I rebooted laptop and phone, created a new project and the asynctask will not execute. What I thought would be a simple FTP upload module, because I've done it dozens of times in other languages, has turned in to a 3 day coding nightmare that only gets worse by the day. I'm creating new problems and not solving old ones.